# Why do we use the reference operator twice?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, reference

My question refers to pointers with classes and the keyword this.

```
class class1 {
public:
    bool isitme(class1& temp){
        if(this == &temp)
            return true;
        else return false;
    }
};


int main () {
    class1 c3;
    class1* c2 = &c3;
    if(c3.isitme(*c2))
        cout << "c3 == c2"; //it is returning that
    system("pause");
}
```

The code above is working, but what I do not understand is why it works only when `bool isitme(class1& temp)` and `if(this == &temp)` are in the same function `isitme()`.

I mean, we already read the block of memory `class1& temp` of temp in the class parameters and should be able to compare that block of memory with the keyword `this`. Why is the function only true when I double get the reference (`this == &temp`)?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` is a pointer, whereas `temp` is a reference. When you write `&temp` in your `if` statement, you are taking the address of `temp`. This converts it to a pointer that can then be compared to `this`.

Comment: So, if a take the reference of a reference, it gets converted to a pointer?

Comment: @Rov You aren't taking reference of a reference. You are taking address of an object passed by reference. Temp is not a reference, temp is an object, passed by reference.

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks. Last question, why do we need to pass it by reference?

Comment: @Rov: If you were to pass it by value, the function would get a copy, and wouldn't be able to meaningfully compare addresses.

Answer (score 2):

Do not confuse reference declarations with use of the address-of operator. When & identifier is preceded by a type, such as int or char, then identifier is declared as a reference to the type. When & identifier is not preceded by a type, the usage is that of the address-of operator.

Taken from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7049scy(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since c/c++ days, but let me take a stab at this...

You're not using the reference operator twice. When you specify `class1&` you're only specifying the type of the parameter (the type is "reference of type `class1`"), not actually doing anything to `temp`. Later you actually dereference the parameter with `&temp`. It's only the second appearance of the ampersand that actually is a reference operator.

Answer (score 0):

The `&` operator within the method declaration simply means that the object passed should not be copied, but rather point to the same location as the object passed to it (it's a reference). The `&` operator in `if(this == &temp)` is needed to actually get the address of that object (a pointer) so that you can compare it to the `this` pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The reference "operator" in the signature of the `isitme` method denotes a reference, that is, an alias for the object itself.

On the other hand, in the line `if(this == &temp)`, the operator is used directly on the object and thus returns the address of the object (a pointer to it).

So, if you want to check if the entered reference is equal to `this`, you need to compare to a pointer, which is exactly what the referance operator returns.

Answer (score 0):

`&` in the class parameter list means the object is passed by-reference. That is, `temp` is an alias for the `class1` object. `&temp` is simply taking the address of that object and comparing it to the object pointed to by `this`. The two syntaxes are semantically different, you're not taking the address twice.